# execute a php page in mpdf and make a pdf

Tags: php, mpdf

mpdf seems to convert html page quite smoothly .. 
but when i use php code which gets value from database then mdpf is outputting the php code in the pdf and not the executed results..

```
 enter code here
    <body>
<form >
<?php 

    include 'connection.php';

    $query="select * from androidlogin";

    $result=mysql_query($query);

    while($i = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<h3>". $i['user']. "&&" . $i['pass']. "</h3>";
    }


?>


</form>
</body>
```

and the output to the pdf file is like

```
<?php include 'connection.php'; $query="select * from androidlogin";  

  $result=mysql_query($query); 
  while($i =mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
      echo "". $i['user']. "&&" . $i['pass']. ""; 
  } 
?>
```

i want the php page to execute and then get converted to pdf , pls help ..

Comment: Useful > http://www.binarytides.com/create-pdf-documents-from-html-using-mpdf-in-php/

Comment: yes but i have a php page .. can't i convert php to pdf ?

Comment: why don't you try tcpdf..?? check it's examples [over here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)..

Answer (score 0):

Please make changes in your php.ini file.Open dll extension in Your file this will solve your problem.